# Can a Webservice be made publicly inaccessible?

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, webservice-client

I am working on a project where a webservice is referenced. I can resolve and add the webservice reference to the project, update it and etc. without issue. I can also paste the URL of the webservice in my browser and have it resolved to see the public methods.

However when I publish the webservice to Azure it consistently fails saying that there is no endpoint and/or the address cannot be resolved.

After trying numerous methods of troubleshooting the issue and modifying different sections of my configuration file as it pertains to the webservice; I figured I'd try accessing the service from outside of my work domain.

When I pasted the URL into a browser from my home I received a "Page cannot be found" error.

I then attempted to resolve the URL from within VS from my home system and I received the same error that Azure has been throwing regarding no endpoint and that the URL could not be resolved.

In the past when I've worked with Webservices, I've always been able to resolve the services from my work or home environment so this is a first for me.

I know that methods within a service can be publicly exposed or hidden but can the actual WebService be made inaccessible to the public as well? And if so, would the "No endpoint" message be the typical result?

I am working with the classic WebService model (asmx) not WCF. If that really makes any difference.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2009/01/07/windows-azure-and-web-services.aspx)

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson - with a summary of the workaround that link would make a good answer.

Comment: Any reason you are using asmx?